# Handle scroll in Jetpack Compose `LazyLayout`

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Recently `LazyLayout` for compose was shared as experimental to try things out. It's used by other lazy implementations for list (column / row) and grid. I wanted to try this out and implement a simple custom lazy layout to consume scrolling and display items lazily (similarly to `LazyList`). The code below is dummy, but the idea is to do something on scrolling offset (in this example I'm placing 3 items with a space of scroll offset).

The problem is that on scroll all composables disappear with `layout` block being called but it doesn't place anything (only initial composition). The answer probably lies somewhere in `LazyList` or `LazyGrid`, but I wanted to avoid copy paste and do something incrementally. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this issue, how to actually handle scrolling with `LazyLayout`.

I tried replacing `scrollable` with `verticalScroll` but it gives same results.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomLazyLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable (String) -> Unit
) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    var firstId by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var firstOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LazyLayout(
        modifier = modifier
            .clipScrollableContainer(Orientation.Vertical)
            .scrollable(
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                reverseDirection = false,
                interactionSource = null,
                flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior(),
                state = scrollState,
                overscrollEffect = ScrollableDefaults.overscrollEffect(),
                enabled = true
            ),
        itemProvider = object : LazyLayoutItemProvider {
            override val itemCount: Int
                get() = 10

            @Composable
            override fun Item(index: Int) {
                content("$index")
            }

        },
        measurePolicy = { constraints ->
            val list = mutableListOf<Placeable>()

            var i = firstId
            while(i < firstId+3) {
                val m = measure(i, constraints)
                if (m.isNotEmpty()) {
                    list.add(m[0])
                }
                ++i
            }
            val height = list.first().measuredHeight
            var positionY = 0
            layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
                for (placeable in list) {
                    placeable.place(0, positionY + scrollState.value)
                    positionY += height
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks you for sharing your LazyLayout implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved if I move `scrollableState` outside of `layout` block to `measurePolicy`. To be precise this code will actually mimic regular scroll effect:

```
        var positionY = -scrollState.value
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            for (placeable in list) {
                placeable.place(0, positionY)
                positionY += height
            }
        }
```

Previously on scroll only `layout` block was called. Now both are (measure and layout). I'm still quite unsure if I'm doing it the right way, but items are composed only once so I guess it's working.